# 意図せず動作している Node.js のプロセスを確実に停止するには？

Tags: linux, macos, node.js

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

### 【質問の主旨】

ブラウザのアドレスバーに`localhost:8080`を入力してアクセスすると、過去にNode.jsで起動したことがあるものの、すでに停止したと思われるページが表示されます。

この表示を停止させて **「このサイトにアクセスできません localhost で接続が拒否されました。」** と言う画面に表示するためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

### 【質問の補足】

#### 1.

クライアントPCはmacOSでブラウザはGoogle Chromeを使用しています。下記の作業を行いましたが、ページは表示されたままです。

```
右クリック
↓
[検証]
↓
ブラウザのアドレスバーの左にある[リロード]にカーソルを当てる
↓
[キャッシュの消去とハードの再読み込み]をクリック
```

#### 2.

Qiitaで[バックグラウンドで動作するNode.jsプロセスを停止させる](https://qiita.com/oishihiroaki/items/85035b81ee13ec5f05c2)というページを見つけました。その記事によると、実行中のプロセスを一覧表示すると言うコマンドとそのプロセスを停止させるコマンドが紹介されています。

```
$ ps -e | grep node | awk '{print $1}'
54044
63221
63239
63241
63637
65703
```

とりあえず実行中のプロセスを一覧表示する`ps`コマンドを実行すると上記のプロセスIDが返ってきました。ですがプロセスを停止させる、

```
$ kill -9 [プロセスID]
```

はまだ実行していません。`kill`コマンドは使ったことがなく、果たして本当に使っても良いかどうか分かりません。

---

以上、ご確認よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

今回のケースでは、node.jsプロセスは問題なく終了されていたものの、`localhost:8080`に**Service Worker**が登録されたままであったために`localhost:8080`にアクセスすると依然としてページが表示されていたと考えられます。

Service Workerはオフラインの状態でもページを動作させる機能を持つため、node.jsプロセスを終了して`localhost:8080`のサーバーにアクセス不能にしたり、あるいはキャッシュを消したりしても`localhost:8080`を開くとページが表示され続けることがあります。

Service Workerの登録を解除するは、`localhost:8080`でChromeのデベロッパーツールを開き「Application」タブに移動しService Workersというところを開きます。下の画像のようにService Workerが登録されていれば、Unregisterリンクをクリックして登録を解除します。これにより`localhost:8080`を開いてもページが表示されなくなることが期待されます。

[image: Applicationパネル]

Comment: Faily Feely さん。コメントありがとうございます。Google Chromeの「Application」タブから「Unregister」リンクをクリックしました。ご指摘のように`localhost:8080` にアクセスすると、「このサイトにアクセスできません localhost で接続が拒否されました。」という画面が表示されます。おかげさまで質問を解決することができました。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

node以外のサービスが動いている可能性がありますので
現在ポートを使用してるプログラムを表示できる`lsof`コマンドを用い

```
lsof -i:8080
```

と実行して下さい。

表示された結果の`PID`という項目がプロセスIDですので、
こちらを`kill -9 [プロセスID]`で停止させれば表示されなくなるはずです。

Comment: ironsand さん。 コメントありがとうございます。`lsof -i:8080` をターミナルで実行してみました。ただエラーは出なかったものの、`localhost:8080` の表示はされたままでした。`lsof`コマンドの存在ははじめて知ったので今後の参考にさせていただきます。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

> killコマンドは使ったことがなく、果たして本当に使っても良いかどうか分かりません。

使っても問題ありません。

`kill -9 [プロセスID]` は対象のプロセスにSIGKILLを送ることでプロセスを終了させます。本番環境で動いているサービスなどならともかく、開発用に動いており不要であると感じている場合、SIGKILLを送信しプロセスを終了させてしまっても問題ないでしょう。

参考：[Man page of KILL](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/procps/man1/kill.1.html)

Comment: PicoSushi さん。コメントありがとうございます。`kill -9 [プロセスID]` を実行しました。ただ実行ができたプロセスは`54044`だけでした。残りのプロセスについて`kill`を実行すると、`-bash: kill: (プロセスID) - No such process` という結果が返ってきます。また`localhost:8080` には過去に表示されたページがそのまま表示された状態です。もし`kill -9 [プロセスID]` を使う以外に今回の質問を解決する方法をご存知でしたらご教示を願います。たびたびの質問で恐れ入りますがご確認をよろしくお願いします。