# プログラムがどのポートを使っているかを調べる方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

Rails の勉強を始めたばかりなのですが
Linux 上で Rails サーバーを起動してもブラウザでアクセスしても何の反応も有りません

ログには

```
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000
```

とでるのですが本当にポートをリッスンできてるかどうか調べる
Linux コマンドはないですか？

Comment: [この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/56791/16894)にある様に、lsof コマンドで調べる事ができます。`sudo lsof -i tcp:3000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ポート状態を確認するためのコマンドは

```
sudo netstat -antp
```

でいいと思います。

が、

> - Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
> - Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000

にある通りListenしているのはループバックインターフェースのため外部のブラウザからはアクセスできません。外部からアクセスできるようにするにはListenするIPを指定しましょう

サーバ起動時のパラメータで指定できます。以下は一例です。

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: まさにそれでした